# Effective way to redraw object using contours

Tags: opencv

**Problems**

Having an image with many blobs. I required to remove blobs that do not meet the requirement. However, the blobs that meet the requirement do have a holes inside. I need to redraw back the successful blobs. Here are some of the code that I used. Hopefully someone can point out how to deal with it.

```
/// Find contours
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
cv::findContours( srcImg, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Point(0,0) );
```

more info (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments#findcontours)

```
/// Start to iterate to each contour found

vector<vector<Point> >::iterator itc = contours.begin();
vector<Rect> rects;

Mat dstImg = Mat::zeros( srcImg.size(), CV_8UC1 );

    //Remove patch that are no inside limits.    
    while( itc != contours.end() ) {
    /// eliminating blobs here
    }

/// To redraw the contours. Error here since some blobs already been removed
int idx = 0;
for( ; idx >= 0; idx = hierarchy[idx][0] )
{
Scalar color( 255, 255, 255 );
drawContours( dstImg, contours, idx, color, CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy );
}

/// To redraw the contours but the holes also filled
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++) {
Scalar color = Scalar(255,255,255);
drawContours( dstImg, contours, i, color, CV_FILLED, 8, noArray(), 0, Point() );
}
```

Do I have to use findContours again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe there are two problems here. First, you want to remove the contours found within contours? To do this, use CV_RETR_EXTERNAL instead of CV_RETR_CCOMP. Second, you want to only draw the contours that weren't removed? This depends more on how you removed the other contours. A simple and quick way to get around this would be to create a new vector > and push_back contours that don't get thrown away in your while loop.

Comment: I see. However, if I required to use drawContours even the holes will be filled right?

Comment: The parameter CV_FILLED, means that the contours will be drawn filled-in. You can change this value is that is not what you want.